# After using .sort_values on a dataframe. I want to access the index that it provides while sorted

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

So when I used `df["total"].sort_values(ascending=False)[:5]` on my dataframe column I got this.

```
lganame      

Melbourne (C)               32052

Brimbank (C)                18001

Greater Bendigo (C)         15648

Hobsons Bay (C)             15285

Golden Plains (S)           14677
```

I sorted so it would be top5. Now I have this information, however I want to be able to access the index name while also being able to have the corresponding total with it.

For example I want to be able to extract that Melbourne (C) has the highest total and that total is 32052.

I tried to index the object it gave me but all it gives me is the number with no way to record the lganame.

Should I use a different method of sorting or is there some way to access the index and number.

Comment: As you need other columns then sort the DataFrame rather than the column, e.g. `top = df.sort_values(by='total', ascending=False)[:5]`. Then the top `lganame` is `top['lganame'][0]`

Comment: @AChampion I tried this however I can only access the number via this method if i do top_lganame[0]. It will give me 32052 with no hint at lganame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
df["total"].sort_values(ascending=False)[:5].to_frame().loc['Melbourne (C)']
```

Or:

```
#use number index
df["total"].sort_values(ascending=False)[:5].to_frame().iloc[0:1]
```